# Optimizing an equation - show the length of an equation, including operators

Tags: expression-manipulation

A simple, but I think useful question to know the answer for.

How can I quickly count the length in my equation, including +,-, and so on?

For example, $x^2+1$ has a length of 4.

Comment: The first would be 5 (any spaces are ignored). The second, output at 1/2 would be 3. But I see more thought needs to go into this.

Comment: It neither simple, nor well defined question. The closest I can think of is [`LeafCount`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LeafCount.html).

Comment: I think LeafCount looks like a very good method for my purpose.

Comment: In Mma the length of an expression is a well-defimed thing. `Length[x^2 + 11]` yields 2, rather than 5. I conclude that under the term "length" the OP understands something different from what one expects in Mma. Therefore, the question in its present form is misleading. I would recommend to reformulate the question and bring it in agreement with the Wolfram language. Otherwise, I think in its present form the question should be closed.

Answer (score 2):

```
f = StringLength@*StringDelete[WhitespaceCharacter]@*ToString
```

seems to do what you're looking for.

```
f[x^2 + 1]
(* 4 *)

f[x^2 + 11]
(* 5 *)

f[1/2]
(* 3 *)
```

Comment: Of note is that `ToString[]` accepts a second argument controlling the kind of string returned, e.g. `StringLength[ToString[x^2 + 1, InputForm]]` vs. `StringLength[ToString[x^2 + 1, StandardForm]]`